# pass arithmetic operation with http get request

Tags: java, spring

I am required to pass an arithmetic operation like `2+8` to a restful back-end and receive the result. I know that a simple operation can be handled in frontend using javascript, but i just want to follow the requirement.

I send the operations with the following uri:

```
http://localhost:8080/?question=2+5
```

and in the back-end i have:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getAnswer(@RequestParam("question") String question){

    System.out.println("recieved question is: "+question);
    return botService.Evaluator(question);
}
```

When i print the `question` it is like `2 3` so there is no operation there.
And the component complains with:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:2 Expected ; but found 5
2 5
  ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 2
```

So, **why the** `+` **is missing?
and how can i fix it?**

Comment: a "+" in a url is just a space. You need to encode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `URLEncoder` class to make sure any special characters are encoded safely for transport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the '+' symbol as the server will just translate it as a space.

Send...

http://localhost:8080/?question=2%2B5

Answer (score 0):

You need URL Encoding here. for more details regarding URL Encoding please have a look in below link.

[URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)